# aws-load-balancer-scheme: internal does not create an NLB, no error

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, eksctl

aws-load-balancer-scheme: internal does not create an NLB, no error, it just never creates the NLB

If I use the deprecated service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true", it works fine.

However, the annotation documentation says to use scheme instead.

Here is my full code:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nlb-sample-service1
  namespace: test
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: instance
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internal
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb

spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

I've tried a number of different variations of that, nothing I tried works when scheme is used.

What am I missing here?

Is there any way to get an error?  kubectl create -f service-file.yaml runs without any errors to stdout.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use load balancer type `external` along with `internal` scheme as shown below:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internal
```

For details, please refer to [kubernetes doc](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/service/nlb/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `kubectl describe service nlb-sample-service1 --namespace test` to checkout the service.